# Lucene is not matching strings having upper characters

Tags: lucene, character, standardanalyzer

I am using Lucene Search Engine (v36), with the StandardAnalyzer. I use the MultiFieldQueryParser.

One of my fields is set as NOT_ANALYZED, because it's a version name containing alphanumeric characters and points. When this field contains an upper character, the search finds no results. Any Idea ?

Details:

The field contains values like:

- version1.26.12.test.a
- version1.26.12.test.b
- v1.2
- version1.Dummy

My search is returning results for the three first example above, but not for the last one.

I have not customized Lucene at all except that I bypassed the standard stopwords with Collections.emptySet().

Thanks a lot.
Dimitri

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe if you mark a field as NOT_ANALYZED it is stored as is, however  [StandardAnalyzer](https://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html) uses LowerCaseFilter (and other see link). So if you search for "version1.Dummy", your query string would probably be "version1.dummy" which won't match to the stored string.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. It makes sense, but unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem. Searching for version1.dummy doesn't retrieve any data, but version1.?ummy does. What should I do ?

Comment: you should make sure your query string does not go threw any `QueryAnalyzer`, if the field is NOT_ANALYZED.